# Can't fix with sorting program, and copying arrays?

Tags: c++

This program i have started is supposed take in data and sort it then output it.

The problem i'm having is that when i sort the code and it gets outputted for some reason the first two values become 0's. I assume this is something wrong with my sort function but i can't figure it out. I also want to copy the values withing "data" to a different array "sortedata" but the way i have it setup just sets all the values to zero. Any help with these two problems?

If you try this yourself just know you have to enter in double so just 5 wont work it needs to be 5.0

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//functions

void input(double data[], double size) {


    //enter data
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cout << "Enter data element \n";
            cin >> data[i];
        }

        //output original
        cout << "Original Data: \n";

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (i) {
                cout << ", ";
            }

            cout << data[i];
        }
        cout << "\n";

}
void copy(double source[], double dest[], double size) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        source[i] = dest[i];
}
void sort(double data[], double size) {

    for (int i = 19; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
        {
            if (data[i]>data[i + 1])
            {

                double temp = data[i + 1];

                data[i + 1] = data[i];

                data[i] = temp;

            }
        }
    }

}
void display(double data[], double size) {

    //output sorted

    cout << "Sorted Data \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i) {
            cout << ", ";
        }

        cout << data[i];
    }

}

int main()
{
    //variables
    bool check = true;
    double size = 0;
    double data[20] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    double sortedata[20] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };

    //input
    while (true) {

        //input
        cout << "Enter data item count <1-20> \n";
        cin >> size;

        //check
        if (size < 1 || size > 20) {
            cout << "Item count is NOT within required range. The required range is 1 to 20. \n" << "Bye \n";
            break;
        }

        input(data, size);
        break;
    }
    //copy
    //copy(data, sortedata, size);

    //sort 
    sort(data, size);

    //display
    display(data, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the loop condition in your `copy` function. Is it reallt correct?

Comment: And the sort function, why doesn't it use the passed `size` argument?

Comment: Furthermore, when the user input a size in the wrong range, you *break out of the loop* and continue with the sorting and displaying even though no data was input. Instead `continue` the loop.

Comment: Uh, all the `double size`... I'm sure an integer type would be better.

Comment: Lastly, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your question to show the input, and the expected and actual output. Also take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: thanks some programmer dude, still new to the site ill do that!

Comment: is this homework? If not you should use `std::sort` and `std::vector`, if yes then you should mention it in the question, because homework often has unrealstic constraints and requirements

Comment: Look at the indexes in your sorting loop. Compare to the description of bubblesort you've been looking at.

Comment: Have you ever heard of int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in copy function replace `i <= size` to `i < size`

Secondly, in sort function replace `i < 10` to `i < size - 1`